# How to reduce the space between two figures side by side?

Tags: spacing, subfloats, subcaption

I would like to reduce the space between two figure that are side by side. I am using the following code but I don't know how to do that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}



\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}[tbp]{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img1}
    \caption{traditional.}
     \label{fig:atzeni_trad}
  \end{subfigure}
  %
  \begin{subfigure}[tbp]{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img2}
    \caption{SLS}
    \label{fig:atzeni_sls}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption[.]{Fluoriscent lamp holder. Traditional on left-side, CAD redesigned centered, and SLS manufactured on right-side}
  \label{fig:lamp}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Moreover, do you know how to have the caption of each of the figure at the same hight?

Comment: The optional argument to the `subfigure` environment can either `t`, `c`, or `b`, not a combination of them. There shouldn't be more than a normal interword space between them I believe, if you see more than that it is because there is whitespace in the images themselves, and cropping is in order.

Answer (score 5):

A negative `\hskip` in between reduces the space. Shifting from `[tbp]` to `[b]` aligns the subfigures entirely at their bottoms, including aligning the captions at the bottom. But this also aligns the images at their bottoms; I don't know if you mind this or not.

Here's the modified source; you can change `-2ex` to whatever distance you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img1}
    \caption{traditional.}
    \label{fig:atzeni_trad}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hskip -2ex
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img2}
    \caption{SLS}
    \label{fig:atzeni_sls}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption[.]{Fluoriscent lamp holder. Traditional on left-side, CAD redesigned centered, and SLS manufactured on right-side}
  \label{fig:lamp}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If you want to align captions without aligning the pictures, I think you want `\subcaptionbox`. Here's an example:

```
\begin{figure}    
    \subcaptionbox{traditional.\label{fig:atzeni_trad}}[0.3\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{img1}}
    \hskip -2ex
    \subcaptionbox{SLS\label{fig:atzeni_sls}}[0.4\textwidth]{\vspace*{3em}\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{img2}}
    \caption[.]{Fluoriscent lamp holder. Traditional on left-side, CAD redesigned centered, and SLS manufactured on right-side}
    \label{fig:lamp}
\end{figure}
```

In this case, I've moved the second image up with `\vspace*{}`, but of course you can move it however you prefer. Note as well that `\textwidth` is not redefined inside a `subcaptionbox`, so the `width` argument to `\includegraphics` has changed.

Comment: Yes fantastic!  but what if I want to have the two figure in a precise location that is not the bottom? then how do I align the subcaption?

Comment: Then I think what you want is `\subcaptionbox`. I'll edit my answer to give an example.